# applepay is not working in real device

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, applepay

I implemented apple pay with stripe in ios using swift. So when the time of testing a program it is runs fine with simulators but not in real device. To test the apple pay with real device it doesn't show the payment sheet to process the transaction. My doubt is to test with apple pay with real device can we add test cards to wallet or have the sandbox account ? is required adding test cards to wallet when using stripe gate way? Could you please give me a clarity?

This is my code :

```
import UIKit
import PassKit
import Stripe

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let request = PKPaymentRequest()
    var paymentStatus = PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.failure
    var paymentController: PKPaymentAuthorizationController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func applepay(_ sender: Any) {
        let merchantIdentifier = "merchant.Appplepay"
        let paymentNetworks = [PKPaymentNetwork.masterCard, PKPaymentNetwork.visa,PKPaymentNetwork.amex,PKPaymentNetwork.discover,PKPaymentNetwork.interac]
        if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: paymentNetworks)
        {

            request.merchantIdentifier = "merchant.Appplepay"
            request.countryCode = "US"
            request.currencyCode = "USD"
            request.supportedNetworks = paymentNetworks
            request.merchantCapabilities = .capability3DS
            request.requiredShippingAddressFields = [.phone, .email,.postalAddress,.all]
            request.paymentSummaryItems  = [PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Fancy Hat", amount: 50.00),
                                            // The final line should represent your company;
                // it'll be prepended with the word "Pay" (i.e. "Pay iHats, Inc $50")
                                            PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "iHats, Inc", amount: 50.00),]
        } else {
            // Traditional checkout flow
        }
        func applePaySupported() -> Bool {
            return PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments() && PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: [.amex, .visa, .masterCard])
        }
           // Setup payment authorization view controller
        if Stripe.canSubmitPaymentRequest(request) {
            // Setup payment authorization view controller
            let paymentAuthorizationViewController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request)
            paymentAuthorizationViewController?.delegate = self

            // Present payment authorization view controller
            self.present((paymentAuthorizationViewController)!, animated: true,completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            // There is a problem with your Apple Pay configuration
            print("Failed to present PaymentSheet");
        }

    }

}
extension ViewController : PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate {

    func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didAuthorizePayment  payment: PKPayment, completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void) {
        if payment.shippingContact?.emailAddress == nil || payment.shippingContact?.phoneNumber == nil {
            paymentStatus = .invalidShippingContact
        } else {
            STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(with: payment) { (token: STPToken?, error)-> Void  in
            print("Stripe token is \(String(describing: token!))")
                //self.paymentStatus = .success
                 completion(.success)

        }
        }

    }

    func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

Comment: there is everything nicely [explained by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/) on their own site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions about testing on a real device: You can only add real cards to your wallet to use with Apple Pay, however if you use a test stripe api key, [that is detected by stripe and your real card will not be charged](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay#testing-apple-pay)

<strike>Not sure why the payment sheet isn't displaying on the real device without seeing some code, but you would want to make sure that the device is set up for apple pay, mainly that it has cards added to the wallet (that you support)</strike>

Not all countries [support Apple Pay](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207957) so there isn't always an option to add a card to the wallet, this would mean that the Apple Pay sheet wouldn't display due to `if Stripe.canSubmitPaymentRequest(request)` returning false.

Comment: i updated  my question.i enabled the apple pay in capabilities and added the apple pay certificate in stripe account and created a merchant id in apple developers and added that id to app id. so when i testing with real device i need to add real card to wallet?

Comment: From looking at the Stripe Documentation looks like you need to create the payment request as follows: `let paymentRequest = Stripe.paymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier: merchantIdentifier, country: "US", currency: "usd")` instead of using the standard PKPaymentRequest(). Maybe try that (although not sure this would cause it to stop working on the device but work on the simulator).

Comment: There is no much difference i tried both ways. In Both cases got same error

Comment: Sorry I missed your question in your previous comment. Yes you will need to have a card in your wallet. If you don't have a card then `if Stripe.canSubmitPaymentRequest(request)` will be false which will explain why the pay sheet is not displaying. Make sure you use your Test Stripe Key though so you don't get charged.

Comment: i used apple pay with stripe then stripe doesn't have to provide default sandbox test like brain tree. Brain tree provide sandbox environment default.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean here. You would have needed a Stripe API key for your payments to work, you create a live key and a testing key. Until your app is ready to go live I would use the test key so that you don't get charged. In the Stripe dashboard you are able to switch between the Live and Test data too. Just to confirm, does the Payment sheet appear when you add a real card on your device?

Comment: i didn't add real card to wallet. so i will check it now

Comment: Was this the issue @vijju?

Comment: Yaa i think it was the issue. I tried to add cards to wallet But in wallet i didn't see any option like add credit card or debit card. It shows only install any wallet from appstore or scan the code. I test the code in iphone6.

Comment: The way i am adding cards to wallet is correct or not?@darrenallen7

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204506 this explains the correct way to add a card

Comment: i use iphone6 .in that i didn't see + button to add cards to walllet.

Comment: It’s hard to suggest what your issue with this is without seeing a screenshot or something. Maybe start a chat instead of the comments on here and we can investigate.

Comment: Just one more thing, https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207957 this is a list of the countries Apple Pay is available. Is your's on this list? If its not that probably why you don't see an option to add a card.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167543/discussion-between-vijju-and-darrenallen7).